# what's wrong with toggle. other functions work well?

Tags: jquery

My toggle function is not working. Can you see what is wrong?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kan98w4/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dlop1').hide('fast');
  $('.dlop2').hide('fast');

  alert("jquery is working");

  $('#dev1').click(function() {
    $('.dlop1').toggle('slow');
  });

  $('#dev2').click(function() {
    $('.dlop2').toggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
#development1 {
  border: 5px;
  border: 5px solid #086C14;
  border-radius: 9px;
  background: blue
}
#development2 {
  border: 5px;
  border: 5px solid #086C14;
  border-radius: 9px;
  background: blue
}
#dev2 {
  background: orange
}
#dev1 {
  background: orange
}
p {
  background: yellow
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>
</title>
<body text="black">
<br><br><br><br><br>
<span style="background:green">rt<br></span>
<div id="development1" style="float:left>
<div id="dev1">
<p>tttr</p></div>
<div class="dlop1">
<br>sd
<p style= "background:white">df</p><br>
</div></div><br><br>
<div id="development2" style="float:left>
<div id="dev2">sd
<p>df</p></div>
<div class="dlop2" id="ani2">
<br>sdf
<p style="background:white">sdf</p>
</div>
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p align="center" float="down"><b></b><br>
<b>
<A href="starting.html">introduction</a><br>
<A href="intro.html">parts</a><br>
<A href="motion.html">about handling</a><br>
<A href="step1.html">step 1</a></b><br>
<b><A href="step2.html">step 2</a></b><br>
<b><A href="step3.html">step 3</a></b><br>
<b><A href="step4.html">step 4</a></b><br>
<b><A href="step5.html">step 5</a></b><br>
<b><A href="step6.html">step 6</a></b><br>
<b><A href="step7.html">step 7</a></b><br>
<br>
</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Please POST CODE here - that is the reason you could not link to fiddle - I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 2 end quotes

```
 style="float:left> <<<<<<<<<
```

Also attribute float does not exits

```
<p align="center" float="down"><b></b>
```

Lastly you would want to assign a width to your development divs

```
#development1 {
  border:5px;
  border: 5px solid #086C14;
  border-radius:9px;
  background:blue;
  width:100%; /* here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shared is having flaws
Check this http://jsfiddle.net/3kan98w4/3/

Error 1:

```
 <div id="development1" style="float:left">
```

Error 2:

```
<div id="development2" style="float:left">
```

Error 3:

```
<p style="background:white">df</p><br/>
```

Wherever you are trying to use style attribute, a closing quota is missing due to which the HTML breaks